# useRef hooks doesn't work with lottie-react-native

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I have upgraded my `class component` to `functional component` hooks, but right now the ref does not work.

**Before:**

```
class A extends Component{

   animation = null;

   onPress = ()=> {
      this.animation.play();
   }

   render(){
     return (
        <View>
          <LottieView
            source={require('./file.json')}
            ref={animation => {this.animation = animation}}
          />
          <Button onPress={this.onPress} title='click me' />
        </View>
     );
   }
}
```

The **above code** which it is class `Component` works very well.

But the **following code** which I **upgraded** doesn't work.

Updated code:

```
const A = props => {

   const animation = useRef(null);

   const onPress = ()=> {
      animation.play();
   }

   return (
        <View>
          <LottieView
            source={require('./file.json')}
            ref={animation}
          />
          <Button onPress={onPress} title='click me' />
        </View>
   );
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're missing `.current`.

See working example at: https://snack.expo.io/@zvona/lottie-and-useref-example

```
const onPress = () => {
  animation.current.play();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tested `animation.current.play();` too, but doesn't work.

Comment: @Muhammad hmm hmm... are you having a mismatch between RN and Lottie versions? If you check expo example, it works fluently.

Comment: `lottie-react-native: 3.0.2` and `react-native: 0.59.9`

Comment: This worked for me but now I'm getting an annoying eslint error: animation.current: Object is possibly 'null'. Any ideas on how to prevent this?